# Sharing an image on Twitter on Android

Tags: android, twitter

I basically have this test code of which I have tried different variations. In this example I have already checked the package_name ("*com.twitter.android*") exists and is installed:

```
  if (package_name.equals("") == false) {
    Intent intentCanLaunch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name);
    if (intentCanLaunch != null) {
      //--
      //
      //--
      if (v == buttonShare) {
        //--
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setPackage(package_name);
        //--
        // shareIntent.setClassName(package_name, "com.twitter.android.PostActivity"); // not working either
        //--
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri_internal_fileprovider);
        //--
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"ekstra_text");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,"ekstra_title");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"ekstra_subject");
        //--
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        //--
        startActivity(shareIntent);            
      }
    }
```

Using he same code for instagram works (can not pass text though), but for Twitter I get error "*Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick*" in Android code

```
@Override
public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
    if (mMethod == null) {
        mMethod = resolveMethod(mHostView.getContext(), mMethodName);
    }

    try {
        mMethod.invoke(mHostView.getContext(), v);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
    }
}
```

Notice hat all he code is he same for Twitter and instagram, I am simply exchanging "*com.instagram.android*" with "*com.twitter.android*"

Comment: do you intend to share to just specifically Twitter or ?

Comment: The user can select whereto he/she wants to share a photo. No sure i really is applicable with Twitter, but if it is, I would like to support twitter. (But for now, I am jus puzzled about my problem wih above code)